# Vertica - Filter results using HAVING only on some columns

Tags: sql, having, vertica

Is it possible to use the HAVING clause in Vertica only on some of my columns? 
Looking for the most efficient way as I am dealing with millions of rows.

Here's an example of what I am trying to do:
Given the table t:

```
A | B | number
--+---+-------
a | c | 1
a | c | 2
a | d | 1
b | e | 1
b | e | 1
c | c | 1
```

If I run:

```
SELECT A, B, sum(number) as total
FROM t
GROUP BY 1, 2
HAVING sum(number) >= 2
```

I will get:

```
A | B | total
--+---+------
a | c | 3
b | e | 2
```

I would like to somehow be able to apply the HAVING condition just to column A, and not to the (A, B) combination, so that my result will really be:

```
A | B | total
--+---+------
a | c | 3
a | d | 1
b | e | 2
```

Guess I could be doing it like this:

```
SELECT A, B, sum(number) as total
FROM t
WHERE A IN (
    SELECT A
    FROM t
    GROUP BY 1
    HAVING sum(number) >= 2
)
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

But is there a better way?

Comment: You have to explain what is `apply the HAVING condition just to column A` on your second example you return `a | d | 1` so how is that related to `HAVING(a) > 2`

Comment: Sorry for the late response. The reason `a | d | 1` appears is because since the `HAVING` applies just to column A, the total for a is `1+2+1=4`, so anything that takes part in it should appear (`a | c` and `a | e`). Thank you for your kind help.

Answer (score 0):

Your query look ok.

You could use analytic functions, but not sure if that will improve performance. You should try and show us explain plan.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT A, B, total_ab
 FROM (
     SELECT A,
            B,
            SUM(number) OVER (partition by A) total_a,
            SUM(number) OVER (partition by A,B) total_ab
     FROM t
     ) X
 WHERE X.total_a >=2
```